# How to save forloop() with different names in R

Tags: r, for-loop, data-manipulation, nested-for-loop

I have a function and a for-loop, I would like to iterate the same for-loop to 3 times `for(i in 1:3){}` and save the for loop output as a list with different names such as `df.1`, `df.2`, and `df.3`. Many thanks in advance.

```
df <- tibble( a = rnorm(10),b = rnorm(10))

rescale01 <- function(x) {
  rng <- range(x, na.rm = TRUE)
  (x - rng[1]) / (rng[2] - rng[1])
}

for (i in seq_along(df)) {
  df[[i]] <- rescale01(df[[i]])
}
df
```

Expected Answer

```
DF.1
 A tibble: 10 x 2
        a      b
    <dbl>  <dbl>
 1 1      0.624 
 2 0      0.421 
 3 0.551  1     
 4 0.320  0.466 
 5 0.266  0.247 
 6 0.0261 0.103 
 7 0.127  0.519 
 8 0.588  0.0623
 9 0.489  0     
10 0.556  0.540 


DF.2
 A tibble: 10 x 2
        a      b
    <dbl>  <dbl>
 1 1      0.624 
 2 0      0.421 
 3 0.551  1     
 4 0.320  0.466 
 5 0.266  0.247 
 6 0.0261 0.103 
 7 0.127  0.519 
 8 0.588  0.0623
 9 0.489  0     
10 0.556  0.540 


DF.3
 A tibble: 10 x 2
        a      b
    <dbl>  <dbl>
 1 1      0.624 
 2 0      0.421 
 3 0.551  1     
 4 0.320  0.466 
 5 0.266  0.247 
 6 0.0261 0.103 
 7 0.127  0.519 
 8 0.588  0.0623
 9 0.489  0     
10 0.556  0.540
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put the `for` loop code in a function and repeat the code for `n` times using `replicate` -

```
apply_fun <- function(df) {
  for (i in seq_along(df)) {
    df[[i]] <- rescale01(df[[i]])
  }
  df
}
result <- replicate(3, apply_fun(df), simplify = FALSE)
```

`result` will have list of dataframes.

If you want them as separate dataframes name the list and use `list2env`.

```
names(result) <- paste0('df.', seq_along(result))
list2env(result, .GlobalEnv)
```